# Quotient ring of complex polynomials and ideal domain

Tags: complex-numbers, ideals, integral-domain

Let f(X) = X^2 − 2X + 5 ∈ C[X] and 
the ideal generated by f(X) be I = f(X)C[X]. (where C(X) is the set of complex polynomials)
Prove that the quotient ring C[X]/I is not an integral domain.

Since C(X) is commutative and has multiplicative identity 1, so does the quotient ring, satisfying (ID1).

I need to disprove:
(ID2): whenever a, b ∈ C[X]/I satisfy a*b=0, either a=0 or b=0 or both,
or (ID2'): whenever a, b ∈ C[X]/I are non-zero, a*b is also non zero

And that's where I get stuck, can anyone help me?

Comment: *[Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)* is some MathJax tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \Bbb Z/6\,$ is not a domain since $\,2\cdot 3 = 0,\ 2\neq 0,\ 3 \neq 0.\ $ Exactly the same thing happens in your example because over $\,\Bbb C\,$ every quadratic is reducible $\, f = gh,\,$ therefore  $\,g,h\,$ will be nontrivial zero-divisors in $\,\Bbb C[x]/f,\,$ just as were $\,2,3\,$ above.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Remember that in the ring modulo $f(X)$, you can take $f(X)$ to be the zero element.  So, given that complex numbers are allowed, can you factorise $f(X)$ into two polynomials?

(But not $f(X)=(1)f(X)$ or similar, as then one of the factors is zero.)

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{C}[X]$ is factorial, so the question of whether $f$ is prime is the same as whether $f$ is irreducible.

So you need to show that $f$ isn't irreducible.